# Text and shape inside glass

Tags: glass

I try to create a LED glass and there are texts and shapes inside it. I want the text look like this.[image]

And here is my rendering. This isn't what I want. How can I fix it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like it has two glass materials assigned.  The sides have more roughness.